# Stream listener and streamController "talking" asynchronously not working as expected

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, dart-async

I'm trying to understand how to work with Streams starting from the Template flutter code.

the output I'm getting is

```
I/flutter (32673): MyApp build executing
I/flutter (32673): HomePage constructor executing
I/flutter (32673): MyHomePage createState() _MyHomePageState executing
I/flutter (32673): _MyHomePageState constructor executing
I/flutter (32673): Awaiting anxiously for the speaker to start speaking!
I/flutter (32673): _MyHomePageState build() executing
I/flutter (32673): _MyHomePageState /  floatingActionButton: onPressed executing
I/flutter (32673): _MyHomePageState setState() executing
I/flutter (32673): _MyHomePageState build() executing
I/flutter (32673): _MyHomePageState /  floatingActionButton: onPressed executing
```

I was expecting something like this:

```
I/flutter (32673): MyApp build executing
I/flutter (32673): HomePage constructor executing
I/flutter (32673): MyHomePage createState() _MyHomePageState executing
I/flutter (32673): _MyHomePageState constructor executing
I/flutter (32673): Awaiting anxiously for the speaker to start speaking!
I/flutter (32673): _MyHomePageState build() executing
I/flutter (32673): _MyHomePageState /  floatingActionButton: onPressed executing
I/flutter (32673): _MyHomePageState setState() executing
I/flutter (32673): _MyHomePageState build() executing
I/flutter (32673): Topic1 loud and clear
I/flutter (32673): Topic2 loud and clear
I/flutter (32673): Great topic1. APPLAUSE!!!!
I/flutter (32673): Topic3 loud and clear
I/flutter (32673): Topic4 loud and clear
I/flutter (32673): Topic5 loud and clear
I/flutter (32673): Great topic2. APPLAUSE!!!
I/flutter (32673): _MyHomePageState /  floatingActionButton: onPressed executing
I/flutter (32673): Topic6 loud and clear
I/flutter (32673): Great topic3. APPLAUSE!!!
```

here is the code I'm using to understand Streams... What am I doing wrong?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:streams/speaker.dart';
import 'package:streams/listener1.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print ('MyApp build executing');
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title }) : super(key: key) {
    print('HomePage constructor executing');
  }
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() {
    print('MyHomePage createState() _MyHomePageState executing');
    return _MyHomePageState();
  }
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  _MyHomePageState() : super(){
    print('_MyHomePageState constructor executing');
    var listener1 = NumberListener();
    var speaker = NumberSpeaker();
    listener1.listen();                      // Start listening
    speaker.speak();                         // Start speaking
  }
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('_MyHomePageState build() executing');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print('_MyHomePageState /  floatingActionButton: onPressed executing');
          _incrementCounter();
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

import 'package:streams/speaker.dart';

```
import 'dart:async';
class NumberSpeaker {
  final StreamController _streamController = StreamController<int>();
  Stream<int>? get stream {
    return _streamController.stream as Stream<int>;
  }
  int _topicNumber = 1;
  int _numberOfTopics = 20;
  speak() async* {
    while (_topicNumber != _numberOfTopics) {               //Speak all 20 topics
      yield _topicNumber;                                   //yield 1 topic at a time
      print('Topic$_topicNumber loud and clear');
      _topicNumber = _topicNumber + 1;
    }
    _streamController.close();
  }
}
```

import 'package:streams/listener1.dart';

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:streams/speaker.dart';
class NumberListener {
  final speakerStream = NumberSpeaker().stream;
  Future<void> listen() async {
    print('Awaiting anxiously for the speaker to start speaking!');
    await for (var topic in speakerStream!) {                         //wait for the speaker to start
      var wholeSpeach = speakerStream!.listen(
        (topic) {
          print('Great topic$topic. APPLAUSE!!!!');
        },
        onError: (err) {
          print('Error: $err');
        },
        cancelOnError: false,
        onDone: () {
          print('Thunderous  APPLAUSE!!!!!');
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `await for` and `speakerStream!.listen(` in the next line is pointless - they do the the exact same thing

Comment: now that you mention it, it is obvious ;-)
This is a side effect of learning a new framework...when things dont work, I tend to make things worse!

Comment: i know, i know... but do not give up ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final speakerStream = NumberSpeaker().stream;
```

This line connects to a **new** instance of `NumberSpeaker`. You have two `NumberSpeaker` instances, one you are listening to and the other that is actually speaking.

The listener should instead take the stream to listen to as a constructor parameter, so you can pass in the stream of the actual speaker instance you have.

For example:

```
class NumberListener {
  final Stream<int> speakerStream;

  NumberListener(this.speakerStream);
```

and then when you create them:

```
var speaker = NumberSpeaker();
var listener1 = NumberListener(speaker.stream);

listener1.listen();
speaker.speak();
```

For some reason you are returning a *nullable* stream from your getter. Fix that. There is no point in returning a *nullable* stream, it should be just a stream.

Also, take into account what psink wrote in the comments.

Comment: Thanks @nvoigt.... you seem to have the answer.  But I'm not sure how to actually implement what you are suggesting.

Any chance you could provide a code example of what you are suggesting?

Comment: Almost there! ... <br>` 
I/flutter ( 3556): Awaiting anxiously for the speaker to start speaking! <br>I/flutter ( 3556): Oh, there is someone listening! <br>I/flutter ( 3556): Topic1 loud and clear ... <br>I/flutter ( 3556): Topic20 loud and clear <br>I/flutter ( 3556): _MyHomePageState build() executing<br> I/flutter ( 3556): Great topic1. APPLAUSE!!!!<br> I/flutter ( 3556): Great topic2. APPLAUSE!!!! ... <br>I/flutter ( 3556): Great topic20. APPLAUSE!!!!<br> I/flutter ( 3556): Thunderous APPLAUSE!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

With the great help of @nvoigt and @pskink I was able to achieve the result desired... and more!

Now, I'm able to have a responsive app, while carrying out asynchronous code in the background! Now I can leave the temple!

Hope this helps other ForTran/CoBOL old timers like myself.
Project hosted here: https://github.com/SpeedyVV/streams.git

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62722/4AqZ6OkPT3o=/ws
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
D/EGL_emulation( 4966): eglMakeCurrent: 0xde1cce80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd61aa220)
D/eglCodecCommon( 4966): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
I/flutter ( 4966): MyApp build executing
I/flutter ( 4966): HomePage constructor executing
I/flutter ( 4966): MyHomePage createState() _MyHomePageState executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState constructor executing
I/flutter ( 4966): Listener: Awaiting anxiously for the speaker to start speaking!
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Oh, there is someone listening!
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Topic1 loud and clear
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Waiting 1/4 second for applause.
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState build() executing
I/flutter ( 4966): Listener: Great topic1. APPLAUSE!!!!
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Topic2 loud and clear
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Waiting 1/4 second for applause.
I/flutter ( 4966): Listener: Great topic2. APPLAUSE!!!!
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Topic3 loud and clear
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Waiting 1/4 second for applause.
I/flutter ( 4966): Listener: Great topic3. APPLAUSE!!!!
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Topic4 loud and clear
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Waiting 1/4 second for applause.
I/flutter ( 4966): Listener: Great topic4. APPLAUSE!!!!
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Topic5 loud and clear
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Waiting 1/4 second for applause.
I/flutter ( 4966): Listener: Great topic5. APPLAUSE!!!!
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Topic6 loud and clear
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Waiting 1/4 second for applause.
I/flutter ( 4966): Listener: Great topic6. APPLAUSE!!!!
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Topic7 loud and clear
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Waiting 1/4 second for applause.
I/flutter ( 4966): Listener: Great topic7. APPLAUSE!!!!
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Topic8 loud and clear
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Waiting 1/4 second for applause.
I/flutter ( 4966): Listener: Great topic8. APPLAUSE!!!!
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState /  floatingActionButton: onPressed executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState setState() executing
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Topic9 loud and clear
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Waiting 1/4 second for applause.
I/flutter ( 4966): Listener: Great topic9. APPLAUSE!!!!
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState build() executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState /  floatingActionButton: onPressed executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState setState() executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState build() executing
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Topic10 loud and clear
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Waiting 1/4 second for applause.
I/flutter ( 4966): Listener: Great topic10. APPLAUSE!!!!
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Topic11 loud and clear
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Waiting 1/4 second for applause.
I/flutter ( 4966): Listener: Great topic11. APPLAUSE!!!!
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState /  floatingActionButton: onPressed executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState setState() executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState build() executing
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Topic12 loud and clear
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Waiting 1/4 second for applause.
I/flutter ( 4966): Listener: Great topic12. APPLAUSE!!!!
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Topic13 loud and clear
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Waiting 1/4 second for applause.
I/flutter ( 4966): Listener: Great topic13. APPLAUSE!!!!
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState /  floatingActionButton: onPressed executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState setState() executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState build() executing
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Topic14 loud and clear
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Waiting 1/4 second for applause.
I/flutter ( 4966): Listener: Great topic14. APPLAUSE!!!!
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState /  floatingActionButton: onPressed executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState setState() executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState build() executing
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Topic15 loud and clear
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Waiting 1/4 second for applause.
I/flutter ( 4966): Listener: Great topic15. APPLAUSE!!!!
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState /  floatingActionButton: onPressed executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState setState() executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState build() executing
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Topic16 loud and clear
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Waiting 1/4 second for applause.
I/flutter ( 4966): Listener: Great topic16. APPLAUSE!!!!
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Topic17 loud and clear
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Waiting 1/4 second for applause.
I/flutter ( 4966): Listener: Great topic17. APPLAUSE!!!!
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState /  floatingActionButton: onPressed executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState setState() executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState build() executing
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Topic18 loud and clear
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Waiting 1/4 second for applause.
I/flutter ( 4966): Listener: Great topic18. APPLAUSE!!!!
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Topic19 loud and clear
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Waiting 1/4 second for applause.
I/flutter ( 4966): Listener: Great topic19. APPLAUSE!!!!
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState /  floatingActionButton: onPressed executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState setState() executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState build() executing
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Topic20 loud and clear
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: Waiting 1/4 second for applause.
I/flutter ( 4966): Listener: Great topic20. APPLAUSE!!!!
I/flutter ( 4966): Speaker: And that is all I have to say.
I/flutter ( 4966): Thank you for listening.
I/flutter ( 4966): Listener: Thunderous  APPLAUSE!!!!!
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState /  floatingActionButton: onPressed executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState setState() executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState build() executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState /  floatingActionButton: onPressed executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState setState() executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState build() executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState /  floatingActionButton: onPressed executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState setState() executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState build() executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState /  floatingActionButton: onPressed executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState setState() executing
I/flutter ( 4966): _MyHomePageState build() executing
Application finished.
```

This is the new code as per answers given

**main.dart**

```
  _MyHomePageState() : super(){
    print('_MyHomePageState constructor executing');

    var speaker = NumberSpeaker();
    var listener1 = NumberListener(speaker.stream);

    listener1.listen();
    speaker.speak();
  }
```

**listener1.dart**

```
class NumberListener {
  final Stream<int> speakerStream;
  NumberListener(this.speakerStream);

  //final speakerStream = NumberSpeaker().stream;

  void listen()  {
    print('Awaiting anxiously for the speaker to start speaking!');
    //await for (var topic in speakerStream!) {
    var wholeSpeach = speakerStream.listen(
      (topic) {
        print('Great topic$topic. APPLAUSE!!!!');
      },
      onError: (err) {
        print('Error: $err');
      },
      cancelOnError: false,
      onDone: () {
        print('Thunderous  APPLAUSE!!!!!');
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**speaker.dart**

I'm trying to understand how to work with Streams starting from the Template flutter code.

```
import 'dart:async';

class NumberSpeaker {

  final StreamController _streamController = StreamController<int>();

  Stream<int> get stream {
    return _streamController.stream as Stream<int>;
  }

  int _topicNumber = 1;
  int _numberOfTopics = 20;

  speak() async {
    print('Oh, there is someone listening!');
    while (_topicNumber <= _numberOfTopics) {
      _streamController.add(_topicNumber);
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
      print('Topic$_topicNumber loud and clear');
      _topicNumber = _topicNumber + 1;
    }
    _streamController.close();
  }
}
```